# Unable to terminate the wlmscpfs SCP server of DCMTK tool kit

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I use worklist SCP (wlmscpfs.exe on windows 7 OS) process of DCMTK as a worklist SCP server and the findscu.exe is used to get the information from it. Once the client server interaction is over, i want to terminate wlmscpfs.exe. By using the termscu.exe, the wlmscpfs could not be terminated. How the process can be gracefully terminated other than kill process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wlmscpfs tool does not support the Private Shutdown SOP Class that is used by termscu, so the only way to terminate DCMTK's sample worklist SCP is to kill the process.